# My Wordpress site crashes on Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, css, media-queries

I'm building a theme for Wordpress, but it seems it's not working on Internet Explorer, especially above IE 9.

Here is the site: http://icomeg.com.br/

It looks like the background image doesn't resize automatically or something (I'm using CSS3 Media Queries), my site froze completely, I did a research and tried to put this filter:

```
.centered_header{ /*criação das caixas do header */
    position: relative;

    height: 130px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    background-image: url(../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

On Chrome and Firefox works well but in IE it's a completly mess, is someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only problem is that your `background-size` isn't working in IE (9 and under), because over IE 9 it seems to be correct, I think the best solution for you is to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/). You'll be able to choose the `background-size` property and this should fix your problem with your background images.